# API Management Self Hosted Gateway when restarting Docker Container

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

APIM Self Hosted Gateway has been set up using Docker container locally.  When internet is disconnected API calls through SHG (self hosted gateway) continue to work (using "in-memory" config).  Also, while disconnected, API management call to retrieve config stops working, which also is expected.

What does NOT work is, when still running disconnected, the Docker Container is restarted the call to get config doesnt work and Docker doesnt use locally saved config in Docker Volume.  When internet is offline how does Docker Container know to use local config file instead of relying on in-memory config or having to have a good connection to APIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was raised with Microsoft. APIM team confirmed only error code 401 triggers container to start from config. Error codes 502/503 are considered transient.  APIM team plans to fix this soon.  Targeting fix in v1.2.4. APIM Release Notes github repo: https://github.com/Azure/API-Management

Answer (score 1):

With or without internet connection on the host machine when you start the container (per [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/how-to-deploy-self-hosted-gateway-docker#deploy-the-self-hosted-gateway-to-docker)) with the `ENTRYPOINT` as `/bin/sh -c dotnet exec Gateway.Host.AspNetCore.dll $commit_env` in `docker logs` we see:

```
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:43.357 [LoadingConfiguration], message: https://srbose-test-apim.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/srbose-test-apim/gateways/getConfiguration?api-version=2018-06-01-preview, source: ServiceConfigurationSource
```

When the host has internet connection we can see going forward in `docker logs`:

```
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:46.297 [ConfigInitialSyncStarted], source: ConfigurationRepositoryProvider
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.059 [EventSnapshotElected], message: provider: storage, uri: https://apimxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/gatewaysnapshotsxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/snapshot-2019-10-11.gwhost_1.json.gzip, rev: 2, source: events.snapshot
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.074 [ConfigurationRetrieving], message: https://apimxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/gatewaysnapshotsxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/snapshot-2019-10-11.gwhost_1.json.gzip, source: events.snapshot.storage.private
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.649 [ConfigurationLoaded], message: https://apimxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/gatewaysnapshotsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/snapshot-2019-10-11.gwhost_1.json.gzip, source: events.snapshot.storage.private
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.798 [ConfigurationRetrieved], message: https://apimxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/gatewaysnapshotsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/snapshot-2019-10-11.gwhost_1.json.gzip, source: events.snapshot.storage.private
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.801 [LocalLoggerAddedToTenant], message: srbose-test-apim.azure-api.net, source: DefaultLocalLoggerConfigurationFilter
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.802 [LocalDiagnosticAddedtoTenant], message: srbose-test-apim.azure-api.net, source: DefaultTenantDiagnosticConfigurationFilter
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.853 [OperationRouteTableRebuildStarted], message: echo-api;rev=1, source: ApiRouter
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.884 [OperationRouteTableRebuildCompleted], message: echo-api;rev=1, source: ApiRouter
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.897 [LegacyBackendUpdated], source: BackendService
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.898 [EventSnapshotRestored], message: revision: 00000002, datasetId: xxxxxxxxxxxx, source: ConfigurationRepositoryProvider
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.902 [WaitingForRemainingEvents], message: snapshot-rev: 00000002, source: ConfigurationRepositoryProvider
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.904 [EventLoopStopped], source: TableStorageEventLoopFactory
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:49.904 [EventLoopStarted], source: TableStorageEventLoopFactory
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:51.539 [EventsSuccessfullyRestored], source: ConfigurationRepositoryProvider
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:33:51.541 [ConfigInitialSyncCompleted], source: ConfigurationRepositoryProvider
```

Thus, the self hosted gateway application is designed to initiate an initial configguration sync at entry.

If internet connection on the container host is lost after initial configuration sync, the running container still has the configuration synchronized.

When you run `docker stop` or `docker restart` command, the main process inside the container will receive `SIGTERM`, and after a grace period, `SIGKILL`.

The `docker kill` subcommand kills one or more containers. The main process inside the container is sent `SIGKILL` signal (default), or the signal that is specified with the `--signal` option.

In these cases the process exits and the corresponding container filesystem is obliterated. So on `docker start` or `docker restart` the process again starts from the `ENTRYPOINT` and the container filesystem is built according to the container image. Which means it will again attempt to sync configuration when executing from `ENTRYPOINT`. But this time, if the internet connection on the host and therefore by extension on the container is unavailable, it cannot resolve the endpoint mentioned in `config.service.endpoint`.

Thus resulting in:

```
[Info] 2021-08-25T08:32:15.895 [LoadingConfiguration], message: https://srbose-test-apim.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/srbose-test-apim/gateways/getConfiguration?api-version=2018-06-01-preview, source: ServiceConfigurationSource
[Error]2021-08-25T08:32:16.063 [Error], exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name does not resolve
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name does not resolve
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Gateway.Host.AspNetCore.ExternalConfiguration.ServiceConfigurationSource.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<UpdateConfiguration>b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\azp\agent\_work\2\s\Proxy\Gateway.Host.AspNetCore\ExternalConfiguration\ServiceConfigurationSource.cs:line 156
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext), source: ServiceConfigurationSource
```

Instead I would recommend you to `docker pause` the container and then `docker unpause` when you want to resume. This way the process and the corresponding container filesystem will be retained in paused state and it won't have to start over from the `ENTRYPOINT`.

The `docker pause` command suspends all processes in the specified containers. On Linux, this uses the freezer cgroup. Traditionally, when suspending a process the `SIGSTOP` signal is used, which is observable by the process being suspended. With the freezer cgroup the process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being suspended, and subsequently resumed. On Windows, only Hyper-V containers can be paused.

See the [freezer cgroup documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/freezer-subsystem.txt) for further details.

Following are the differences between `docker stop`, `docker kill` and `docker pause` commands.

[image]

Comment: @Srijit_Bose_MSFT - thank you very informative.  MSFT article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview 

states the following: 

When configuration backup is turned on and connectivity to Azure is interrupted:
- Running self-hosted gateways will continue to function using an in-memory copy of the configuration
- Stopped self-hosted gateways will be able to start using a backup copy of the configuration

So question is...when docker is restarted why doesnt it use config saved in local volume/storage?  Per the point made in the MSFT article.